# nltk word pair count using fdist

Tags: python, nltk

I have used FreqDist to obtian count of each bigram appearing in a file, the outout is a list of tuples followed by their count. How can i use a for/while loop to obtain the bigrams with highest counts.

```
raw=open("ex.txt","r").read()
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
words=re.compile('.*[A-Za-z0-9].*')
filtered=[w for w in tokens if words.match(w)]
pairs=nltk.bigrams(filtered)
fdist=nltk.FreqDist(pairs)
type(fdist)

for w1,w2 in fdist.items():
   print w1,w2
```

output:

('having','the') 6
('has','done') 8
('in','the') 2
......
.....

How can i extract the bigrams with the count 6,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreqDist` is basically a dictionary with some fancy wrapping, including that the `keys` are returned in sorted order (see [docs](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html#keys)).

```
fdist.keys()[:2]
```

If you want to extract all keys with a value larger than e.g. 4, use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: fdist[x] > 4, fdist)
```

Comment: I am new to nltk,  So using bigramcollocations totally confused me. Hence i tried this approach.

Comment: using fdist.keys() returns a list of all the bigrams right. So can i use a simple for loop to maintain the count of each pair as it iterates and return the pairs with count greater than a particular number. for ex count>4 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = """This is a foo bar\nsomething something foo foo bar, that doesn't do nothing!\n"""
>>> from nltk.util import bigrams>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize>>> FreqDist(bigrams(word_tokenize(text)))
<FreqDist with 15 samples and 16 outcomes>

>>> for i in x:
...     print i, x[i]
... 
('foo', 'bar') 2
(',', 'that') 1
('This', 'is') 1
('a', 'foo') 1
('bar', ',') 1
('bar', 'something') 1
('do', 'nothing') 1
('does', "n't") 1
('foo', 'foo') 1
('is', 'a') 1
("n't", 'do') 1
('nothing', '!') 1
('something', 'foo') 1
('something', 'something') 1
('that', 'does') 1
```